# Alter multiple columns in the Database based on selected values- Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp

I am displaying the details of a particular table in my JSP page using a for-each loop in the following manner:

```
<c:forEach items="${List2}" var="alist">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="${alist.check}">
        </td>
        <td>${alist.two}</td>
        <td>${alist.three}</td>
        <td>${alist.four}</td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
<input type="radio" id="agree" value="Agree"/>Agree 
<input type="radio" id="disagree" value="Disagree"/> Disagree
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

Now, there is no column named "check" in my DB. It is a transient field in my POJO.  I do have a Agree/Disagree column in my DB. I want to check particular rows, click "Agree" or "Disagree" and on clicking Submit, the Agree/Disagree column for those records should be updated respectively. I'm using Spring MVC with Hibernate. Please tell me if any more info is required from my side.

Comment: Instead it two columns `agree` and `disagree`, why not have a single column and map it to `check` field. And instead of check box you can have radio button.

Comment: I have just a single column. That column needs to be updated with either "Agree" or "Disagree". And I need to update multiple records at once. Hence, checkboxes.

Comment: Once the user clicks on the submit button, I believe on the server side you must be knowing the ids of the entities (or rows) for which you want to update the column to either Agree/Disagree. If so, then you can issue an `HQL update` command along with `in` keyword. Isn't it?

Comment: A single user can Agree or Disagree for different records. He can Agree for one record and Disagree for another.

Comment: it still can be done provided if we have list of record ids that need to be marked `Agree`(call it agreeIds) and list of record ids that need to be marked `Disgree` (call it disAgreeIds). `session.createQuery("update entity_name e set e.column=:status where e.id in (:agreeIdsList)").setParameter("status", "Agree").setParameterList("agreeIdsList", agreeIds).executeUpdate()`. and similarly call the same query again with `disagreeIds` now. Unless I am missing your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with simple jQuery, Set `class`(say `.chkbox` here) to all checkboxes. Whenever any change event happened say,

> - if checked, the value of checkbox added to JS array.
> - If unchecked, the value will be removed from JS array.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var selectedArray = [];
    $('.chkbox').change(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            selectedArray.push($(this).val());
        } else {
            selectedArray.pop($(this).val());
        }
        //alert(selectedArray);   
        $("#textbox1").val(selectedArray);
    });
});
```

Finally I used textbox to hold all the selected checkboxes value. You can make it into a hidden give a name attribute.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" value="101"> This is 101<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" value="102"> This is 102<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" value="103"> This is 103<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" value="110"> This is 110<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" value="111"> This is 111<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" value="112"> This is 112
<br />
<input type="hidden" id="textbox1" name="selectedArray" />
```

Sent it to a controller and split the values by `comma (,)`.

**Update :**

In your code, you can update like this.

```
<c:forEach items="${List2}" var="alist">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" name="check" value="${alist.check}">
        </td>
        <td>${alist.two}</td>
        <td>${alist.three}</td>
        <td>${alist.four}</td>
    </tr>
    <input type="hidden" id="textbox1" name="selectedArray" />
</c:forEach>
```

That's all about required.

See the [**JS Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/vinzykrish/qtz0tgtc/7/) how it works. Hope this helps.

Comment: Every row of the table will have a checkbox and the number of checkboxes is not fixed.

Comment: That's really good, I can see it from your code. It's inside of the loop. I did it for sample. If you try it with your code you can get to know.

Comment: See the updated part, you have to add `class for checkbox` and add `hidden input`.

Comment: "Check" is mapped as a boolean attribute in my class. So, the value passed to the string will be either "True" or "False"

Comment: If you're sending only `true/false`, how will you identify which column it should affect? Here in sample I will send the `ID` of the column. I'm just adding only selected checkboxes, (i.e), true values of particular ID's. Let me know if anything need to explain.

Comment: Your example is clear to me. I just don't know how to implement it in my application.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107961/discussion-between-vinoth-krishnan-and-abhineet-kumar).